# Android: Display string with textView

Tags: android, textview

hello i am trying to display a string with a `TextView`. i am doing this dynamically and this is the code:

```
   LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.Layout);
   EditText  editText=(EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
   Button        button=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            tv.setText(display);
            this.layout.addView(tv);
```

,but it hits an error on `this.layout.addView(tv);` Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Update(full activity code):

```
public class CalendarDate extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar_date);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    String dday = extras.getString("currentday");
    String dmonth =extras.getString("currentmonth");
    String dyear = extras.getString("currentyear");

    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();


    ab.setTitle(dday+"/"+dmonth+"/"+dyear );



    Bundle extraz =getIntent().getExtras();


    String display = extras.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar_date);

   LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.Layout);
   EditText  editText=(EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
   Button        button=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            tv.setText(display);
            layout.addView(tv);
}
```

Comment: in this.layout.addView(tv); says layout cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: try: layout.addView(tv);

Comment: @SoCo can you post the complete activity code

Comment: Tobiel solution should work?

Comment: @Raghunandan i posted it

Comment: @SoCo you have two `setContetnView`. Do you have linear layout in `activity_calendar_date`/

Comment: @Raghunandan yes i have LinearLayout

Comment: @SoCo then it should work

Comment: @Raghunandan yes it works but after while is stops working. Anyway i ll look into it .Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `this`, just `layout.addView(tv);`. Use `this` for referencing instance variables only. (Variables in the class outside of any methods)

Comment: op asked a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642713/android-textview-makes-app-stop. i don't think removing `this` makes a difference