# Android : TextView makes app stop

Tags: android, textview

i have created a `CalendarView` that whenever you select a date a new activity opens.In that new activity i have put a button and a`TextView` and I want that `TextView` to display a string . The thing is that when i select a date a message is shown that says "Unfortunately,"project_name" has stopped!".

here is the new activity's code:

```
public class CalendarDate extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar_date);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String dday = extras.getString("currentday");
    String dmonth =extras.getString("currentmonth");
    String dyear = extras.getString("currentyear");
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setTitle(dday+"/"+dmonth+"/"+dyear );



    Bundle extraz =getIntent().getExtras();
    String display = extras.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE");


    LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.Layout);
    EditText     editText=(EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button       button=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                TextView tv=new TextView(this);
                tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                tv.setText(display);
                layout.addView(tv);


}


public void sceduleEdit(View view) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditSc.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

and here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="CalendarDate" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/Layout">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
    android:onClick="sceduleEdit" />
```

if remove the following code then the activity opens as it was supposed to

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.Layout);
EditText     editText=(EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
Button       button=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            tv.setText(display);
            layout.addView(tv);
```

do you have any ideas why this is happening? Sorry for the long question and thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Display string with textView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641032/android-display-string-with-textview) asked a similar question before .

Comment: Have a look at your logcat output. There should be exception stacktrace there that helps pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Change the EditText to TextView in your activity, You are referencing a textview but casting it to an EditText.

Answer (score 3):

Your layout is

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

and you have : `EditText editText=(EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);`

We have a **ClassCastException** here I suppose, as a TextView can't be cast to an EditText, and so your app crashes.

AFAIK, this should be `TextView textView=(TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);`

Answer (score 0):

The string "display" you are using might be null.Log the value what you are getting in that string. Also in your code the bundle variable you are using is extraz with a 'z' and trying to read it with extras with a 's'.c d logcat if you are getting nullpointer.

```
Bundle extraz =getIntent().getExtras();
String display = extras.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
```

Also your xml doesn't have an edit text.check for textview in your activity instead of editext.

Answer (score 0):

You are typecasting a textview to an edit text in your code. Change EditText to TextView in code other wise it will give a class cast exception